# How to do a ransack search on has_one association and sort by it's existance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I have two models with `has_one` and `belongs_to` associations. I want to sort the model with `has_one` depending on whether the associated object exists.

I can currently sort for example by associated object field.

Here is the simplified code:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :B 
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :B
end

q = A.all.search(params[:q])
as = q.result.includes(:b)
```

I have tried:

```
sort_link @q, :b_id_present
sort_link @q, :b_present

sort_link @q, :b_id_null
sort_link @q, :b_null
```

Comment: Did you solve it?